# HTML Table -- Putting a Link in the Header for Sorting? (No JavaScript)

Tags: python, html, django, hyperlink

I'm dynamically generating a table, as well as the column headers.

How do I make the columns clickable (**NO** JavaScript!), so that when they're clicked, they add a `sort=columnNameHere` entry to the query, and reload the current page with that query?

Comment: What language are you using that dynamically generates these tables?

Comment: @Ian: Good question! I'm using Django.

Comment: How do I pound a nail in with a rock?  (No Hammers)

Comment: @Steven: When your client turns off your hammer, it's not really your choice is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to know your server-side language, but since you didn't include that, you'll want the code to output html as follows...

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th><a href="test.html?sort=Name">Name</a></th>
      <th><a href="test.html?sort=Location">Location</a></th>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

on the server you need to make sure you get the sort variable from the collection of get variables and apply it to the source query. In pseudocode, this would be something like:

```
   currentSort = Request["sort"] 
   data = db.Execute("select * from customersorder by " + sqlescape(currentSort))

  //write table header 
  foreach col in columns
    write("<th><a href='test.html?sort=" + col + "'>" + col + "</a>")

  //close header, start data 
  for each row in data    
    write...
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much I want, except that it erases all queries currently on the page. Also, how do I say "current page"?

Comment: @Tim: Django, sorry I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: looks like request.path gets you current url http://blog.leahculver.com/2008/11/django-url-goodness.html

Comment: @Tim: Ohhh I see what happened here... I was trying to be handling the "current page" on the client side, without realizing that I should be doing it on the server side!! That's very helpful, thanks a lot! +1

Comment: @Tim: Is there a simple way to say "set this query string", without manually needing to handle the `?`, `/`, `&` characters and the potential for duplication?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I would certainly look at using the variable to do that, but you have to pass it as a querystring value, unless you want to change the links to submitting a form, in which case the sort field can be a string in a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to grab the 'sort' variable in your server-side code and resend the query to the data source so your table would be populated in the desired manner.

In order to add the link, you would want to dynamically generate the href so it would append the sort=columnnamehere to the query string.

If you need help crafting the server-side code, please include more details about your set up (scripting language, data source, etc).

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the question here is how I would actually resend the current query with a slight modification, as in here; I can handle the server side easily.